# How can I use Material UI media queries inside fixed-width container?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, media-queries

How can I use Material UI media queries inside fixed-width container?

I have a screen and inside the screen I have another small container, with a size of mobile phone. I need the Material UI media queries to act inside the small container like it's the all screen, to show inside the elements like in mobile view and not like in desktop view even when the global container is in a size of a desktop version.

Thanks

Comment: Would need some form of code to be able to provide you with any type of support

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast response but I don't think that a piece of code will help. It's a simple React.js component with a width of 300px inside a 1200px screen. Inside the 300px component I need the query media of Material UI to act like the screen is 300px and not 1200px